# Cron run every minute ( Runs in bash but not in cron)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

This  have been discussed several times in previous post. I followed given advise but it does not work for me. I have two scripts which are run by the cron service every minute. To my surprise, only  one runs per minute( 1st in the list below), the other fails (2nd in list below). Most surprising, when run direct from the terminal, both scripts execute fine.

```
Cron setup :
*/1  * * * * /home/user/Desktop/scripts/generatepattern.sh
*/1  * * * * /home/user/Desktop/scripts/getnextfile.sh
```

File permissions are:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 user user 522 Jul 25 16:18 generatepattern.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 user user 312 Jul 25 23:02 getnextfile.sh
```

The code for the non-schedulable( not running in cron ) is :

```
#!/bin/bash
#Generate a file to be used for the search
cd /home/user/Desktop/scripts
no=`cat  filecount.txt`
if test $no -lt 20
then
    #echo "echo less"
    #echo $no
    expr `cat filecount.txt` + 1 >filecount.txt
fi
```

Comment: just use `mail` command to check for reported cron errors.

Comment: Does the second job rely on the work done by the first job? There is no guarantee they will run in a predictable order. If they rely on work done by each other you should combine the two into one script, or write a third script that runs both, or make one cron that runs `script1 && script2` instead.

Comment: Also, a minor note: `*/1` indicates to step through the minutes range `0-59` with a step value of `1`. That's exactly the same as just saying `*` with no step value.

Comment: @DanLowe Its importatnt that I keep the execution of the scripts separate since they do different jobs.

Comment: Are you sure it's not running? If something's wrong with filecount.txt, the `test` expression will fail, the `if` won't execute, and the script will do nothing. I'd suggest adding some logging to the script so you can tell more about what's happening. Also, note that cron will run both scripts at the same time rather than sequentially, so it may be triggering a race condition you don't see when running them from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the main issue was that the new cron settings only get used when the vi editor gets closed. Changes have to be made on the editor and a :wq command issued so that the new settings get installed. Just issuing :w command does not work since no install happens(this was my mistake). I realised this after issuing :wq command on vi and the following output displayed :-

```
# crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
```

Thanks to all other suggestions made.

Answer (score 1):

In the last line you wrote `cat filecount.txt` instead of `cat /home/user/Desktop/scripts/filecount.txt`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I have made that edit and tried 1 minute. Still couldn't execute.

#!/bin/bash
#Generate a file to be used for the search

cd /home/user/Desktop/scripts
no=`cat filecount.txt`
if test $no -lt 20
then
    #echo "echo less"
    #echo $no
    expr `cat filecount.txt` + 1 > filecount.txt
fi

Comment: Can you show us the current content of `/home/user/Desktop/scripts/filecount.txt`?